# Python mixins: object.__init__() takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, mixins

I have a question related to Python mixin classes. This is my code:

```py
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Base; {}; {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Mixin1(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Mixin1; {}; {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class Mixin2(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Mixin2; {}; {}'.format(args, kwargs))
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class C(Mixin1, Mixin2, Base):
    pass
```

When I call `c = C(arg1=10, arg2=20)` I get the following error:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

I understand why I get this error: `Base.__init__()` calls `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, which is `object.__init__()` and doesn't accept any parameters. Is there a way to fix this in a clean way?

One solution would be to omit the `*args` and `**kwargs` in the `Base` class and only call `super().__init__()`. But this fails if somebody writes `class C(Base, Mixin2): pass`. Another solution would be an `try ... except` clause around every `super()` call, which seems neither a good solution to me.

Has anybody an idea how to deal with that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `super` in the `Base` class?

Comment: To deal with `class C(Base, Mixin2): pass`, for example.

Comment: But you don't have to call `super` in any of your parent class. There's no need. Am I correct in guessing that you're trying to use `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` as a way of creating class attributes for each class?

Comment: What do you mean with *fix* this in a clean way? It makes perfectly sense to raise an exception here, you constructed an object with parameters, and those objects are illogical. Not raising an exception would probably result in a lot of trouble later.

Comment: Yes, I want to initialize attributes in each class. What do you mean by there's no need to call `super` in any parent class? If I omit it in all mixins only one `__init__` is called.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So you would "catch" all needed parameters in each Mixin per name, so that **kwargs and *args are empty when object.__init__() is called?

Comment: @joe-92: ideally, yes. Since otherwise the caller somehow has a wrong idea of what is constructed, and it could be dangerous to let that pass silently.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the question, I've just had the same issue, where I'm defining a set of mixins, each of which pop some arguments out and past the rest to their superclass. They can be initialised in any order.

I bumped into this error because I made the slightly different mistake of not defining the base class (to accept the `(self, *args, **kwargs)` function signature) at all.

What I (and presumably you) want is a `Base` class which:

- accepts *args and **kwargs so you can use any combination of your mixins
- meets @Willem Van Onsem' concern in the comments that arguments vanish silently if you simply don't call them.

That would look something like this:

````
class ResourceBase:
    """ Allows you to use any combination of mixin classes which pass unused *args and **kwargs up to their superclass,
    without encountering:
    ```
    Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
    ```
    on initialisation.

    The case of passing extra args and kwargs to your class constructor which aren't popped by the various
    mixins is still handled safely with the same error (to prevent loss of variables and poorly defined behaviour
    later).
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Constructor for ResourceBase
        """
        if (len(args) > 0) or (len(kwargs.keys()) > 0):
            # Initialisation has gone all the way up to the base class and there are still parameters in *args or **kwargs. Scream at the user (you could probably give a more helpful error message than this)
            raise TypeError('object.__init__() takes no parameters')
        super().__init__()
````

This allows you to create and use, in any order, any number of mixins with a signature like:

```
class MyMixin:
    """ Mixin to do a thing with an important kwarg.
    Notice how `my_important_kwarg` is popped out of the kwargs in the constructor signature, so shouldn't end up at the base class.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, my_important_kwarg=None, **kwargs):
        """ Constructor for MyMixin
        """
    
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Do something with your my_important_kwarg
        self._my_important_kwarg = my_important_kwarg
```